# Не выводятся значения полей из всех записей - выводится только из первой записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомный тип записей testimonials

```
add_action('init', 'create_testimonials');
function create_testimonials() {
    register_post_type('testimonials', 
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name'   => __('Отзывы'),
    ),
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag')
}
```

Вот вывод

```
<?
$featured_posts = get_field('testimonials_posts');
if( $featured_posts ):
    foreach( $featured_posts as $post ):
        setup_postdata($post);
        $testimonial_author_prof = get_field('testimonial_author_prof_2');
        echo $testimonial_author_prof;
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Но

```
echo $testimonial_author_prof;
```

Выводит только значение из первого поста. Как вывести значения всех постов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод сделан неправильно. Сделайте через [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query)

```
<?php
        $args = [
                    'post_type' = > 'testimonials',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'desc' 
                ];
        
        $the_query = new \WP_Query($args);
        
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        
             while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
             
                 $testimonial_author_prof = get_field('testimonial_author_prof_2', $the_query->post->ID);
                
                  echo $testimonial_author_prof;
             
             endwhile;
        
        endif;
        
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: the_title() выводит а вот echo $testimonial_author_prof; не выводит

Comment: @Denis 'testimonial_author_prof_2' - это acf поле? оно определено? если заголовок выводится - значит выборка прошла успешно, глобальная переменная определена и получение поля acf тоже должно пройти

Comment: Да это ACF поле. Но значение его известно

Comment: @Denis скорректировал ответ. попробуйте сделать вызов с айди поста

Comment: Почему то не получается. Сначала сделал кастомные поля и создал первый отзыв. Потом пришлось поменять кастомные поля и добавил еще два отзыва. Вот значения с первого отзыва перезадал для новых полей. Вот значения с первого отзыва выводились а с остальных нет. Удалил первый отзыв и теперь нечего не выводится

Comment: Нашел выход. Сделал кастомные поля не в группе а каждое поле само по себе ))) Спасибо вам Valerii Vasiliev!!!

Comment: @Denis ок. если ответ помог - можно отметить его принятым и проголосовать за него

Comment: Помечено)))!!!!